# Implementing IS-A cardinality in Flask SQLAlchemy and Marshamllow schemas

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a table called `User` which holds general information for all the users registered in the system:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    sign_up_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    archived = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
```

Then I have two sub-types of user, each containing all of the above columns, plus some type specific columns. For example:

**Class Customer:**

```
class Customer(User):
    __tablename__ = "Customer"
    # USER is a CUSTOMER
    address = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
```

**Class Driver:**

```
class Driver(User):
    __tablename__ = "Driver"
    # USER is a DRIVER
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    profile_picture_path = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
```

**Class WarehouseManager:**

```
class WarehouseManager(User):
    __tablename__ = "WarehouseManager"
    # USER is a WAREHOUSE MANAGER
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    profile_picture_path = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    warehouse_name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
```

and so on.

The problem arises whenever I try to create this with `db.create_all()`, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column 'first_name' on class WarehouseManager conflicts with existing column 'User.first_name'.  If using Declarative, consider using the use_existing_column parameter of mapped_column() to resolve conflicts.
```

Also I don't exactly have an idea about how I'd create schemas in Marshmallow for this.

To be clear, I want the database for Driver to contain the `user_id` and all the additional fields (first_name, last_name, profile_picture_path), but when I am interacting with the database via SQLAlchemy I want to be able to enter the `User` columns in the `Driver` table I.E.:

```
driver = Driver(email="driver@gmail.com", first_name="Driver Name"...)
```

instead of:

```
user = Users(email="driver@gmail.com"...)
driver = Driver(user_id = user.id, first_name="Driver Name"...)
```

I see the ladder as repetative and bad practice in terms of using a quality ORM. A quality ORM should handle these common cases with ease. This is not the first time I have been dissapointed by ORM's limited capabilities, especially when handling temporary tables, materialized views, triggers and so on.

**Edit:**
I have tried adding `use_existing_column` in the `db.Column` for `first_name` and `last_name`. I still got the same error.

**Edit 2:** [Here](https://t.ly/hgibN) is a sandbox which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    role = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(256), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    sign_up_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    archived = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

class Customer(User):
    __tablename__ = "Customer"
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'customer'}
    
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    address = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

class Driver(User):
    __tablename__ = "Driver"
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'driver'}
    
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    profile_picture_path = Column(String(256), nullable=False)

class WarehouseManager(User):
    __tablename__ = "WarehouseManager"
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'warehouse_manager'}
    
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    profile_picture_path = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    warehouse_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
```

This way, you have a common `User` table, and each subtype (`Customer`, `Driver`, `WarehouseManager`) has its own table with additional columns. The `__mapper_args__` parameter helps SQLAlchemy to understand the inheritance structure.

Regarding Marshmallow, you can create separate schemas for each type and use `fields.Nested` for the common fields:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class UserSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    role = fields.String()
    email = fields.String()
    password = fields.String()
    sign_up_date = fields.DateTime()
    archived = fields.Integer()

class CustomerSchema(UserSchema):
    address = fields.String()
    name = fields.String()

class DriverSchema(UserSchema):
    first_name = fields.String()
    last_name = fields.String()
    profile_picture_path = fields.String()

class WarehouseManagerSchema(UserSchema):
    first_name = fields.String()
    last_name = fields.String()
    profile_picture_path = fields.String()
    warehouse_name = fields.String()
```

This way, you can use these schemas to serialize and deserialize your objects based on their types.